# Play Games Achievements not getting unlocked

Tags: android, google-play-games, achievements

I've looked all over the web for this one and I couldn't find anything, what am facing here is that whenever I try to unlock an achievement via the code:

```
Games.achievements.unlock(getApiClient(), "id");
```

the damn thing won't unlock ! and I have published my app on the play games and its live, the hash keys are sure to be correct because it logs into the play games, I've checked the key hash for each achievements and nothing is wrong there either, I started pulling my hair after trying:

```
Games.achievements.unlockImmediate();
```

So I came running to you guys :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use `unlockImmediate()`, you can set a listener to check for the outcome of unlocking an achievement.

Use this code:

```
Games.Achievements.unlockImmediate(getApiClient(), "id").setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<UpdateAchievementResult>() {

            @Override
            public void onResult(UpdateAchievementResult res) {
                System.out.println(res.getStatus().getStatusCode());
            }

        });
```

This will unlock the achievement, then give you a status code to tell you the result. Check the code you get against [this list of codes](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/games/achievement/Achievements.UpdateAchievementResult.html). It should be **STATUS_OK** which has a status code of **0**. If it isn't, you can check what it returned to see why it went wrong.

Good Luck.

Comment: @AhmedAwad I think you should leave the question open. It's a good question and I think it will help others that stumble upon it :)

Comment: Will do, but one more thing, the response code is 3007 which indicates that the achievement is unknown .. I don't know how to solve this thing really, I mean I checked the code (for the achievement itself) and its correct, also worth mentioning, I noticed that the pointes I entered are being multiplied by 100.. I don't know am really confused on this one

Comment: @AhmedAwad I get the feeling that the ID you have supplied for the achievement is wrong, where are you getting it from?

Comment: Ooops ! terribly sorry for this one, my eyes tricked me and I wrote an l ( small L ) instead of an I ( capital I ) you can blame the boss's mac on this typo -_- .. got it to work finally ! thanks Ogen :-)